# Php form is emailing me, but not sending the form contents

Tags: php, html, forms

I am having trouble getting my form to send me the user filled form data. Below is the HTML for the form and the PHP. The form is being sent to me, but I am not sure if I set up the HTML and PHP correctly. I've tried digging around for answers, but I don't have a lot of knowledge in PHP and most of the other questions have more complex forms. Trying to take what I've learned from looking for the answer, I think I've Frankensteined everything. Please help.

```
    <form  method="post" action="contact2.php" enctype="text/plain">
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input name="name" type="text" id="name">
      <label for="email">Email Address</label>
      <input name="email" type="text" id="email">
      <label for="phone">Phone Number</label>
      <input name="phone" type="text" id="phone">
      <label for="comments">Comments</label>
      <textarea name="comments" id="comments" rows="5" cols="38"><?php echo $comment;?></textarea>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>


<?php
$to      = 'myemail@myemail.com';
$subject = "Message from my internet form";
$message .= $_POST['name'];
$message .= $_POST['email'];
$message .= $_POST['phone'];
$message .= $_POST['comments'];
$headers = 'From: ' . $_POST['name'] . $_POST['email']  . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: notsure@whatgoeshere.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
  header('Location: http://mypage.com/thankyou.html');
exit();
?>
```

edit: updated the above code to reflect my changes. I'm still not getting the form info to my email and the email I receive looks funny, "www@myemailprovider.com" it starts with www and looks like it's coming from me instead of the user filling out the form.

edit2: This works now and all code is updated. For the curious, I was able to format the incoming message by putting a table in my PHP form. It looks like this:

```
<?php
$to      = 'you@youremail.com';
$subject = "This is the subject line for the email you receive";
$headers = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: ".$_POST['Name']." <".$_POST['email'].">\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n";

    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
     $message = '
  <table>
     <tr><td>Name:</td><td>'.$name.'</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Email:</td><td>'.$email.'</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Phone:</td><td>'.$phone.'</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Comments:</td><td>'.$comments.'</td></tr>
  </table>';

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
  header('Location: http://yourpage.com/thankyou.html');
exit();
?>
```

Comment: You should not be using `enctype="text/plain"`

Comment: Should I just get rid of it altogether?

Comment: Yeah, it's just not necessary. In addition to adding `name` attributes in your form, when adding new things to your `$message` variable, use `.=` to append instead of just `=`

Comment: @mattslone totally missed that, but should still be getting the comments in the email?

Comment: Fixed the form to add name="_" for each form field, and also removed the enctype and added the .= to append, but I'm not really seeing what else I could be doing wrong... I even created a new folder on my server to make sure I'm not cached.

Comment: Okay, this works now. Maybe I was cached after-all. Do you have any suggestions on formatting the data that comes to me? It looks like it all runs together on one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`POST` variables require that a `name` attribute be included with your inputs.

Try this:

```
<form  method="post" action="contact2.php" enctype="text/plain">
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input name="name" type="text" id="name">
      <label for="email">Email Address</label>
      <input name="email" type="text" id="email">
      <label for="phone">Phone Number</label>
      <input name="phone" type="text" id="phone">
      <label for="comments">Comments</label>
      <textarea name="comments" id="comments" rows="5" cols="38"><?php echo $comment;?></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Tried this, but the form is still sending me an empty email. I'm also not sure how this is happening, but the email I receive is from www@myemailprovider.com

Comment: If you're using Chrome, check the network tab, it's very helpful when troubleshooting form requests. https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/network-performance/resource-loading#view-details-for-a-single-resource

Look under the "view details for a single resource section."